# Oneline horizontal list with middle item that fits its content width

Tags: css, responsive-design, inline, nowrap

I have a horizontal list of items, arranged with display:table-cell.

The middle item can vary in content length, and it should expand accordingly.
And obviously its siblings should shrink to make space to it.

Here is a sample of what I did until now:

http://codepen.io/Pictor13/pen/mJoyXw

But the middle item still overflows over the right sibling, when the content grows.

Is it possible to achieve what I want? Are `display: table-cell` and `white-space: nowrap` the right approach?

**Note:** the width, if specified, should always be generic and not fixed to a specific px/em.

Comment: if you remove table-layout: fixed on the UL it goes to one line, but the B C E and A cells get small.  You could add a min-width: 5 or 10% if needed: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvmveP

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Qbojzq do it with divs instead

Comment: @deebs yours is the best solution for now. It doesn't wrap when it shrink too much and keeps staying on one line. I don't like that the sibling items are not automatically flexible but with *min-width* is a good compromise. I'd like so much to find a way to make the middle item to shrink or use some overflow strategy, but just when there is not space anymore, while taking the available space when there is enough. But I don't know if it is even possible (maybe with flex? o.O)

Comment: @RachelGallen I can't use divs, I need to keep the semantic meaning of the list. But I guess it makes not much difference when playing on *display* property. Unfortunately when resizing/shrinking the window in your *CodePen* the sibling items wrap to a new line :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wellll....`flexbox` can do that.

```css
.container {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 1px;
}
li {
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  background-color: green;
  color: red;
  list-style: none;
}
ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 3px;
  background-color: brown;
}
li {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
  -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
input {
  width: 270px;
  width: inherit;
}
form {
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li class="middle">
      <form>
        <input type="number" value="123123418190238901390812903823" min="1" max="123012301232138192738798127398712983" />
        <span>to page and with some long  content</span>
        <button>go</button>
      </form>

    </li>
    <li>E</li>
    <li>A</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/OVqPwv)

Comment: It works on Chrome but the items are all stacked vertically on Firefox :(

Comment: Added vendor-prefixes to above and Codepen. Looks OK in FF when I checked now.